# Chain Rule Basics

Tags: calculus

Say I have:

$f(x,h(x))$

I would like to evaluate:

$$\frac{\partial f(x,h(x))}{\partial x}$$

At first sight it seemed as rather straightforward chain rule, but I (somewhat disappointed) got stuck on it...

EDIT: I suspect that the to continue the evaluation we would have to know more about the function?

Comment: Yes, the final result depends on what the functions $f,h$ are.

Comment: Is there anything I could say more about this partial derivative?

Comment: Ellya has already answered this, but the partial denotes the part of the derivative that explicitly depends on x. That is $\partial f(x,h(x))/ \partial x \neq d f(x,h(x))/ dx$. So in its current form you can't simplify what you are trying to evaluate.

Comment: Ok, I thing I got it. Ellya is referring to the derivative as the best operator that would make a linear approximation of the function, which is $f ' (x, h ( x ) )+\frac {\partial f}{\partial h}h ' (x)$, correct? (which is suppose I what $d f(x,h(x))/ dx$ refers to.

Comment: She evaluated $\frac{d[f(x,h(x))]}{dx}$, which represents the total change in $f$ with respect to $x$.

Comment: She would be a he! Damn my name! Lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer would be $f ' (x, h ( x ) )+\frac {\partial f}{\partial h}h ' (x)$

Comment: Could give any reference on that?

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule look down the page at the higher dimensions bit, there's some sums that are used.

Comment: Great thanks!!!

Comment: No worries! Hope it helps!

Comment: Wait, if $f$ takes two variables, what exactly is $f^\prime$?

Comment: @AndréNeves $f'$ is the rate of change of $f$ with respect to its input, it does not matter if the input is a scalar or a vector, it describes what happens when the input changes infinitesimally (small).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure if I understand... That input needs to be specified, doesn't it? In this case, since $f(x,h(x))$ would be a function of only $x$, is $f'(x,h(x))=\frac{\mathrm df}{\mathrm dx}(x,h(x))$?

Answer (score 0):

***NOTE:*** *maybe this is effectively the same as ellya's answer, but I'm not sure about it and, if it is so, I'll gladly delete this. I decided to write this anyway to expose the train of thought that leads to the answer. Also, please take it easy on me; in case of errors, I'll be paying attention to the comments.*

I'm not a mathematician, but it strikes me that, since $f = f(x, h)$, for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ you shouldn't care about the $h$ bit. That is, there shouldn't be any $\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}$ in the answer. In my opinion, this is the heart of partial derivation, right?

Example: $$f(x, h) = x + he^h\ln h$$

Then: $$\frac{\partial f(x, h)}{\partial x} = 1$$

**HOWEVER,** if $h$ can be expressed in terms of $x$ only, and you decide to write $f$ in terms of it (which seems to be the case), then you have effectively created a new function $g(x) = f(x,h(x))$ which is univariate. For this new function, there is no partial derivative, only a total derivative, which is in $x$, such that: $$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = \frac{\mathrm dg}{\mathrm dx}$$

From the definition of $g(x)$, that means: $$\frac{\partial f(x,h(x))}{\partial x} = \frac{\mathrm df(x,h(x))}{\mathrm dx}$$

Which needs the chain rule and (maybe this is what ellya means) is equal to: $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial h}\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}$$

If we insist on our previous example, we'd have: $$\frac{\partial f(x,h(x))}{\partial x} = 1+\left(h^\prime e^h\ln h+h^\prime he^h \ln h + e^hh^\prime\right)h^\prime$$